# Can't resolve data from http.get() with Angular 2.0.0

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I need to preload data on some url, so
I've resolver:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, } from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ProfileResolver implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(
        private _http: Http
    ) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<any>|any {

        return this._http.get('/session').map(data => {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        });
    }

}
```

and component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';


@Component({
    selector: '[profile]',
    host: {
        class: 'profile-page app'
    },
    template: require('./profile.html')
})

export class Profile {
    constructor(
        private route:ActivatedRoute
    ) {
        this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
    profile;
}
```

Route config:

```
    { 
      path: 'profile',
      loadChildren: () => System.import('../profile/profile.module'),
      resolve: {
        profile: ProfileResolver
      },
    },
```

`Console.log` in resolver shows received data, but in component it's empty object, whats wrong? When I used this code in rc4, all was fine.
Also if I change `return _http.get(...)` to simple value, like `return "123";` this code will work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found my data in `this.route.snapshot._resolve.parent.resolvedData`, but what the proper way to get it?

Comment: Also for the record `http.get()` will result in a `Response` object and you should call `.json()` or `.text()` to actually get the response data.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching your data can (and should) be done via

```
this.profile = this.route.snapshot.data['profile'];
```

Entire and complete explanation can be found here: 
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html